# Two Multi Dimensional Array with Objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I would like to use an NSDictionay (I think this is the correct method) to save data to in a class which is accessed by other classes:

.h

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSArray   *NameKey;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSArray   *DataFields;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSDictionary *MDArray;
```

.m

```
@synthesize NameKey;
@synthesize DataFields;
@synthesize MDArray;

- (id) init
{
        NameKey = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"DeviceName",nil];
        DataFields = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Serial", nil];
        MDArray = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:DataFields forKeys:NameKey];
}
```

Couple of questions:

1. Is this the correct method for setting up an NSDictionary?
2. How you I add/delete/modify the data. Assuming that the name was unique

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI - standard naming conventions dictate that variable and method names should being with lowercase letters. Only class names start with uppercase letters.

Comment: Also, the use of `@synthesize` is largely out-of-date. And why is your dictionary named `MDArray` and not `mdDictionary`? And do you really need properties for the two arrays? That data will be in the dictionary.

Comment: And why has the property `nameKey` with the type `NSArray` a singular form? And … Why does no one read introductions before posting on SO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved this was to:

```
devices = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
dataFields = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Name",@"Type", nil];

NSArray *addDevice = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"MM-TEST",@"-- --", nil];
NSDictionary *infoblock = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:addDevice forKeys:dataFields];
[devices addObject:infoblock];
```

Seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use modern syntax:

```
MDArray = @{ @"DeviceName": @"Serial" }
```

If you want a mutable version you can send it the `mutableCopy` message